# What's the expected format of identifier in the JavaFX Gradle plugin?

Tags: java, javafx-gradle-plugin

In the [JavaFX-Gradle-Plugin](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin) there's an option called identifier:

```
// gradle jfxNative
identifier = null  // String - setting this for windows-bundlers makes it possible to generate upgradeable installers (using same GUID)
```

and I can't find the equivalent in the [jafaxpackager's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafxpackager.htm).

What's the expected format of this option?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in this documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html#sthref59

> Tries to use the application identifier as [UpgradeCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372375(v=vs.85).aspx).
> If the application identifier is not a valid GUID, then a random [GUID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368767(v=vs.85).aspx) for UpgradeCode is generated.

UpgradeCode is defined as:

> The UpgradeCode property is a GUID representing a related set of products. The UpgradeCode is used in the Upgrade Table to search for related versions of the product that are already installed.
>
> This property is used by the RegisterProduct action.
>
> ## Remarks
>
> It is strongly recommended that authors of installation packages specify an UpgradeCode for their application.

And GUID:

> The GUID data type is a text string representing a Class identifier (ID). COM must be able to convert the string to a valid Class ID. All GUIDs must be authored in uppercase.
>
> The valid format for a GUID is {XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX} where X is a hex digit (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,B,C,D,E,F).
>
> Note that utilities such as GUIDGEN can generate GUIDs containing lowercase letters. These must all be changed to uppercase letters before the GUID can be used by the installer as a valid product code, package code, or component code.